# dynamically create tree graph using multiple lists in python

Tags: python, list, tree

I want to create a tree graph from multiple lists in python.

I have 4 lists.

```
list1[]  # list 1 is the root node
list2[]  # list 2 contains response data got by sending a value in list 1
list3[]  # list 3 contains response data got by sending a value in list 2
list4[]  # list 4 is the last node
```

All the list are one dimensional.

Each element in parent node consists of it's own list.

```
list1[0] will have it's own list2[] data
list1[1] will have it's own list2[] data
list1[2] will have it's own list2[] data
```

and so on..

Similarly,

```
list2[0] will have it's own list3[] data
list2[1] will have it's own list3[] data
list2[2] will have it's own list3[] data
```

and so on..

same goes for `list3[]`.

[I want to create a tree dynamically like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywwxX.png)

Lists are of same length for each level.

```
ie. list2 retured by list1[0] and list1[1] will be of same length.
```

Comment: Please read - [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822). Specifically "Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first". And "Ask about specific problems with your existing implementation".